# How to update states and contracts of a corda network

Tags: blockchain, corda

I am a beginner in Corda. I am developing a project using Corda OS. Whenever I change a little bit of code in states or Contracts I have to deployNodes again so that nodes will be aware of the newer version of cordapp But, this deletes the old data. Is there any way to update cordapp without redeploying the nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can rebuild a specific module (e.g. `contracts`) with `./gradlew :contracts:build`.
- Take the resulting `jar` file from the `build` directory and place it inside the `cordapps` folder of your node.
- Restart the node.

Comment: is there any way to build all the elements of the cordapp all at once?

Comment: Also, I am also using accounts library so there are two more files in the node's cordapps folder which are :accounts-contracts-1.0, accounts-workflows-1.0. How to rebuild these jars

Comment: No there is no way; it's either `deployNodes` which rebuilds everything or the method that I told you about. As for the library jar files just copy paste them; you don't have to rebuild them unless you change the library version in `build.gradle`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Adel